# Trust boundary violation even after validation check in java webapp

Tags: java, security, checkmarx

I am trying to fix security issues, which is given by checkmarx scan. In type, "trust boundary violation". i have tried multiple solutions, but none seems working.

I have tried validation check, which is provided by most other solutions and also tried cannonicalization. but it is still not working.

```
public static String sanitize(String inputString) {

if (!inputString.matches("[-0-9a-zA-Z_]+")) {
    return null;
}

return ESAPI.encoder().canonicalize(inputString.replace("/", "").replace("..", ""), false, false);    
}
```

Issue shown by Checkmarx: This element’s value flows through the code without being properly sanitized or validated and is eventually stored in the server-side Session object. (Trust boundary violation)

Comment: may i know the source of the input that you are trying to sanitize?

Comment: Input is taken from header of request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a wellknow "bugs" for this Checkmarx Query;  The Trust Boundary violation ([CWE-501](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/501.html)). The problem could be is you will store the data in the session with sanitized and no sanitized object. As I see you're code, you seems to do some sanitization. I think this is your right whitelist.

If you do this(sanitization), you should consider it as a "False Positive" . I know Checkmarx working on it after reporting some of them. This should be better in next Checkmarx releases